# D/I marking on LCD pinout

Tags: lcd, pinout

On most of the schematics it is RS (Register select) but I can't figure out what D/I (pin 4) mean, I haven't found anything about that. What could it mean ? The datasheet indicate it's the register select pin, but I'm interested in the D/I meaning

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Data/Instruction". It does the same thing as Register Select but is more explicit about it.

Comment: I just had a flash at the same moment your answer showed up ! Thanks !